# Cordova/Phonegap -- making an app restart after memory invalidation? (eg: RAM manager)

Tags: android, cordova

When I use my Android 4.2.2 RAM manager (a Samsung feature?) to clear memory, it invalidates memory in my Cordova/Phonegap app. If I try to use it again, it hangs and does nothing. I have to force close it in the program list.

Is there a way to make my app restart if memory is invalidated like that?

Comment: What is a "RAM manager"?

Comment: My opinion: don't use a ram manager. Let Android manage its memory and resources on its own (it will almost always do a better job than you or a third party can). If Android decides it needs to kill your app in order to free some memory, at least it will do so correctly. With a third party app, who knows what it is doing. Of course, if your app can't recover from a normal Android termination, *then* you have a problem that needs fixing. Otherwise, this really falls into the "not supported" category, in my opinion.

Comment: It is not a 3rd party app. RAM manager is a built-in function. Actually this may be a Samsung addition -- if I press the middle button on my Note 2, there is a pie chart. I press that and get a RAM manager. So the question is how to figure out when the user cleared memory with the RAM manager, so that the app restarts when the user goes back to it instead of hanging. I have noticed some of the apps I have hang if I clear memory with the RAM manager, while others restart. Here is a link: http://samsunggalaxysforums.com/showthread.php/6987-What-is-happening-when-quot-Clear-Memory-quot-is-clicked